# Como puedo poner una variable proveniente de php a js. El código es algo así

Tags: javascript, php

*Quiero que esta variable se muestre en la notificación:
**$i = "Hola Mundo"**, ya que la variable obtiene los datos de una base de datos, me pueden a ayudar, ya que he intentado pero no se ejecuta el código :(*

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function notifyMe() {

if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
}


else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

  var notification = new Notification("Aqui ira la variable php ($i)");
}


else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
  Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {

    if (permission === "granted") {
      var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    }
  });
}

}
</script>
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
```

Comment: var notification = new Notification("<?=$i?>");

Comment: Listo... gracias!!

Comment: @John pon eso como respuesta, para que pueda ser aceptada y la publicación esté completa.

Answer (score 0):

Como poner una variable proveniente de php a js.

Este es un ejemplo, donde se obtiene el valor de la variable `$val` desde PHP

```
<?php
  $val = getValue();
```

En la misma página se tiene código `JavaScript` y se necesita que el valor de la variable `$val` se pase como parámetro, se realiza de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
     myMethod(<?=$val?>); 
</script>
```

---

Por lo tanto, si tienes definida tu variable `PHP` como:

```
$i = "Hola Mundo"
```

puedes hacer referencia de la variable de esta forma `<?=$i?>` para usarla en `JavaScript` de esta forma

```
var notification = new Notification("<?=$i?>");
```